# No Tests Running with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js

I've setup a model that I would like to unit test in Ember but every time I run the test suite, no matter what I do, I get 0 tests ran.

```
$ ember test
version: 1.13.1
Built project successfully. Stored in "/Users/BenAMorgan/Sites/frontend/tmp/class-tests_dist-pjaTeNtp.tmp".

1..0
# tests 0
# pass  0
# fail  0

# ok
No tests were run, please check whether any errors occurred in the page (ember test --server) and ensure that you have a test launcher (e.g. PhantomJS) enabled.
```

The model:

```
// app/models/feature.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

What the test looks like:

```
// tests/unit/models/feature-test.js
import { moduleForModel, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForModel('feature', 'Unit | Model | feature', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  needs: []
});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
  var model = this.subject();
  // var store = this.store();
  assert.ok(!!model);
});
```

All the npm dependencies installed without errors. Testem is installed. PhantomJS is installed via npm. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Try updating to latest Ember CLI.

Comment: Sometimes you can see more information if you run the tests in the browser, start a server (`ember serve`) and then go to http://localhost:4200/tests in your browser. Hopefully you'll get a helpful message.

Comment: Also, run phantmjs -v and ensure phantomjs is installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation, My `test/index.html`  hasn't the ember app script.

**How to solve it?**

Go to your `test/index.html`, look for the lines:

```
{{content-for 'body'}}
{{content-for 'test-body'}}
```

Below this you will have your scripts, check the name of your ember app file. In this case is new-app

```
<script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/test-support.js"></script>

<!-- ==  THIS ONE IS YOUR EMBER APP == -->
<script src="assets/new-app.js"></script>
<!-- == THIS ONE IS YOUR EMBER APP == -->

 <script src="testem.js"></script>
<script src="assets/test-loader.js"></script>
```

**Check module prefix name**

In `config/environment.js` you will find module prefix property. Example:

```
  ... config starts over here
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'fenix-5-ui',
    ... more properties here
```

**Get the test running**

To get your tests running you just need to rename the script in `test/index.html`. In this case I changed `<script src="assets/new-app.js"></script>` for `<script src="assets/fenix-5-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: This answer is pretty good. My problem was my script files were not in the right order. I put `tests.js` before all the others. Boked everything. I found this:


[tests/index.html example](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/blueprints%2Fapp%2Ffiles%2Ftests%2Findex.html)

and this answer. Both are useful to look at.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to remove ember-cli-blanket to make tests run again in Ember CLI 1.13.15.